# How do I get a usemap working within a firefox XUL document

Tags: firefox, xul, imagemap

In my XUL I have the following code fragments:

```
<map name="KeypadMap">
<area href="javascript:pad('A')" coords="1,1,31,31" shape="rect"/>
</map>
...
<hbox flex="1">
 <image src="./keypad.png" width="32" height="32" useMap="#KeypadMap"/>
</hbox>
```

The image displays just fine, however, when I mouse over, the cursor does not change to a hand, and clicking does not call the pad function.

Similar code works fine in straight HTML, so there must be some trick to get it working via a Firefox XUL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a namespace to embed HTML inside of XUL. Check this [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Adding_HTML_Elements).

Comment: <html:map name="KeypadMap">
<html:area href="javascript:pad('A')" coords="1,1,31,31" shape="rect"/>
</html:map>
...
 <html:img src="./keypad.png" width="32" height="32" usemap="#KeypadMap"/>

this gives me the image which shows up as an expected <img> with properties, but usemap still doe

Comment: Also requires using id instead of name

    <map id="KeypadMap">